# Proving that an equation has a solution

Tags: calculus

> If $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers, prove that the equation
>   $$\frac{a}{x^3+2x^2-1}+\frac{b}{x^3+x-2}=0$$ 
>   has at least one solution in the interval $(-1,1)$

My solution is as follows, I could not be sure on its correctness. If you have any other solutions, could you please share them?

**My attempt:**

Let$$f(x)=\frac{a}{x^3+2x^2-1}+\frac{b}{x^3+x-2} = \frac{a}{(x+1)(x-(\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}))(x-(\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}))}+\frac{b}{(x-1)(x^2+x+2)}$$

Then, the two summands have distinct signs in the interval $(\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2},1)$. Therefore, $f$ *might* take on the value zero in this interval.

We know that $f(x)\rightarrow-\infty$ as $x \rightarrow 1^-$ and $f(x)\rightarrow\infty$ as $x \rightarrow (\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2})^+$.

Then, for a sufficiently small $\delta>0$, $f(1-\delta)<0$ and $f(\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}+\delta)>0$. Also, $f$ is continuous on $[\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}+\delta,1-\delta]$. Thus, from the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exist at least one $c\in(\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}+\delta,1-\delta)$ such that $f(c)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, edited..

Comment: I hope I have did not make mistake in factorization.

Comment: Nice work. The singularity at $\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ has to be dealt with, and you did that efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch of solution.** May be unstable. :-)

Rewrite $f(x)$ as

$$
f(x) = \frac{a(x^3+x-2)+b(x^3+2x^2-1)}{(x^3+2x^2-1)(x^3+x-2)}
$$

and denote the numerator by

$$
g(x) = (a+b)x^3+2bx^2+ax-(2a+b)
$$

and the denominator by

$$
h(x) = (x^3+2x^2-1)(x^3+x-2)
$$

Note that $h(x)$ has a zero (and therefore $f(x)$ has a pole) at $x_0 = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$.  In this vicinity, $h(x)$ goes from positive to negative.

Now,

$$
g(x_0) = \frac{3\sqrt{5}-9}{2}
$$

which is a negative number, while $g(1) = 2b$, a positive number.  Therefore, in the interval $(x_0, 1)$, $f(x)$ goes from a large positive number to a large negative number.  Since there are no other poles in this interval, there must be a zero in that interval.

Comment: I got the solution, it is more direct usage of the IVT. What about mine?

Comment: Seems fine to me. You asked for other solutions, I thought I might as well toss one out there. :-)